# How to customise mouse pointer using rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows, ruby-on-rails-4

How to create a folder inside the rails view page and also customise the mouse pointer using rails...If i right click the mouse it will display the option like:

`open,new,rename,delete using mouse.(example:windows)`

In before anyone tried like this its possible? I don't know how to search it how to find the better way on this task.....

**html.erb**

This is my view of

```
  <%@folder.order("folder_name ASC").each do|i|%>

  <div class="col-md-2">

  <i class="fa fa-folder fa-1x" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; 
  <%=link_to i.folder_name,users_image_browse_path(i)%>

  </div>

  <%end%>

  <a style="width: 12%;" class="btn btn-block btn btn-success hvr-sweep-to-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#applyModal"><i class="fa fa-plus "></i> Create Folder</a>
```

**view page:**

```
  <div class="modal fade" id="applyModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="applyModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog_2">

      <div class="modal-content" style="margin-top: 180px;">

        <div class="modal-header">

          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true"></span></button>

          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">

            <div class="head_4">

              <div style="font-size: 47%; font-family: times;">Create New Folder</div>

            </div>

          </h4>

        </div>

       <div class="modal-body">

        <%= form_for Folder.new,:url=>{:controller=>"users",:action=>"create_folder"} do |i|%>

          <div class="section">

            <%= i.label :folder_name,:style=>"font-family: t;"%>

            <%= i.text_field :folder_name,:value=>"New Folder",:class=>"form-control",:autofocuse=>true ,required:true%>

          </div>

          <div class="section" align="center">

            <%= i.submit "Save" ,:class=>"btn btn-info"%>

          </div>

       <%end%>

       </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
```

**Controller.rb**

```
def new_folder
 @folder=Folder.new
end

def create_folder
  @folder=Folder.new(folder_params)
  @folder.update(:project_id=>$p_id,:parent_folder_id=>$f_id)
  if @folder.save
    redirect_to :action=>"image_browse"
  else
    render "image_browse"
  end
 end
```

**Model View:**

```
  class Folder
   include Mongoid::Document
   field :folder_name, type: String
   field :parent_folder_id, type: String
  field :project_id, type: String
 end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Do this:**

```
def create_folder
@folder= params[:folder][:name]
Dir.mkdir @folder
end
```

for nested directory do this:

```
def create_folder
@folder= params[:folder][:name]
require 'fileutils'
FileUtils::mkdir_p @folder
end
```

**Hope it helps**

Comment: how to use your answer in my rails app

Comment: Update ur question including your method in controller code

Comment: Answer Updated please check.